# Compile C/C++ with gVim 8.1 in Windows 10 (MinGW)

Tags: c++, vim, windows-10

Since everything is 32-bit, I used `:set makeprg=mingw32-make`, and then tried compiling via `:!make`, which gave the following error message:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> shell returned 1

I tried the basic "Goodbye World" stuff:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Goodbye World";
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Other than being a noob.

Comment: Surprisingly even the simplest `:!gcc %` didn't work.

Comment: Have you made sure the `MinGW/bin` directory is set in your local environment variable PATH? (are you using TDM MinGW installed with Code::Blocks? or installed by the mingw-installer?)

Comment: Yep, there's a `C:\MinGW\bin` directory in my environmental variable PATH list.

Comment: The Vim is not translating your `:set makeprg=mingw32-make` setting an alias for `make` (e.g. `alias make=mingw32-make`). If you test, you can call `mingw-make` from your `cmd.exe` or `powershell` terminal right?

Comment: Uh...if you mean when I invoke the `make` command in `cmd.exe` instead of doing `:!make` in Vim command line, then no, it still shouts back the same thing I got from Vim.

Comment: Oh and I'm using MinGW from the Installer.

Comment: OK, I've been playing with this in Vim8.1 on Win7. I can't get `make` to work despite setting `:set makeprg=mingw32-make` either. All I can do `:!mingw32-make` and it works fine. I'm out of ammo on this Vim question.

Comment: Hmm, I can't even get `:!mingw32-make` to work for me. Just says "Nothing to be done for 'goodbyeworld.cpp'." Could you help me out on this one?

Comment: Well, that shows `mingw32-make` was successfully called and it checked the dependencies for `goodbyeworld.cpp` and nothing needed to be updated and you should either have an `a.out.exe` or `goodbyeworld.exe` already made (or you do not have the dependencies set up correctly in your `Makefile`)

Comment: I have `goodbyeworld.exe`, so thank heavens my `Makefile` isn't flawed; however, my goal is to see the "Goodbye World" either in console or terminal or any observable way. Would this require additional tinkering to the `_vimrc` file?

Comment: No, not really, just `:!goodbyeworld.exe` will run it and hold the terminal open for you. (personally I just use a short script to build small projects rather than a `Makefile` for the option handling flexibility) For single-source builds, I just add `map \g <Esc>:gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -o %< % <CR>` in my `.vimrc` so I simple hit `ctrl+v, \g` to compile the current file into its `filename.exe` (you can map another key for `g++`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:!make` doesn't run `'makeprg'`. It runs `make`. Since you are specifically trying to run `mingw32-make.exe`, presumably you don't have an executable named `make.exe`. (See `:help :!`)

`:make` runs `'makeprg'`. (See `:help :make`, `:help 'makeprg'`)

> my goal is to see the "Goodbye World" either in console or terminal or any observable way. Would this require additional tinkering to the `_vimrc` file?

You would rather want to do it by tinkering with your makefile. Any arguments to `:make` will be passed to `'makeprg'`. If you defined targets `clean` (to remove the Make artefacts) or `run` (to execute the product of your Make), you will be able to write `:mak clean` or `:mak run` in Vim to run those targets. Obviously, you can create your own commands and/or mappings to make those `:make` commands faster.

Comment: Well I used `:make` instead of `:!make` and, since `makeprg` already being defined that way, I got the "Nothing to be done for 'goodbyeworld.cpp'." message. However, this doesn't either a) make a Makefile or b) make an executable file. What should I do next?

Comment: That means your make was run correctly. The rest of the issue is in your makefile, and is not a Vim issue. I suggest you ask a new question, posting the contents of your makefile (as we can't know what the problem is without it), and tag it with [tag:makefile] and [tag:mingw] (to attract people who are familiar with those technologies). But typically, `make` should just compile your executable. not run it (add a `run` target as described above so you can do `:make run` in Vim to run it).

Comment: Hmm guess I have a LOT of learning to do regarding this mysterious "Makefile" stuff, but at least there's no more problem Vim-wise, so that should be good news. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Note (and I completely overlooked this myself, silly me) that when you run a simple code, such as the one above, that does not need extensive file managements and Makefiles, all you need to go is `:!gcc %` for C and `:!g++ %` for C++. I believe (and I may be wrong, but this is a simple observation) that in Vim, `:!` indicates the following commands are to be executed in the system Command Prompt, and `gcc/g++` is the command to invoke the GNU Compiler for C and C++ respectively. Finally, `%` is used to indicate the current filename, with all extensions intact. This is extremely useful in cases of keymapping, as I have done via the following:

```
nnoremap <F5> :!g++ %<CR>|"Press Func.5 to Compile via GNU Comp.
```

Comment: You are correct about `:!` -- you can confirm in [`:help :!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3a%21). For compiling a single file you should try [SingleCompile plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115), which provides a mapping similar to the one you created here, but adapts for different OSs and programming languages.